# Portable oxygen concentrator

Tags: usa, tsa, medical-devices

If I travel with a portable oxygen concetrator but I am not using it on the plane does it still have to be an FAA approved device.
I only use it at night with a CPAP machine.

Answer (score 1):

> does it still have to be an FAA approved device

[American Airlines](https://www.aa.com/i18n/travel-info/special-assistance/mobility-and-medical-devices.jsp) states :

> FAA Regulations prohibit the use **and transportation** of other personal oxygen units, including those that contain compressed or liquid oxygen because they are classified as hazardous materials.

[Delta](https://www.delta.com/us/en/accessible-travel-services/assistive-devices-medication) states :

> If you **do not intend** to use your **FAA approved** PAP machine during your flight, you may bring it on board and are not required to travel with 150% of battery life for the flight time. The battery must still comply with airline requirements.

[United](https://www.united.com/en/us/fly/travel/accessibility-and-assistance/oxygen.html#compressed-gas-poc) doesn't state explicitly that it must be FFA approved, but I would infer that the same rules apply to United as well

> If you don’t need to use your POC during your flight, you can bring it as a carry-on or in a checked bag with the batteries removed

---

The [TSA](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/items/nebulizers-cpaps-bipaps-and-apaps) states :

> Nebulizers, CPAPs, BiPAPs, and APAPs Carry On Bags: Yes (Special
> Instructions) Checked Bags: Yes (Special Instructions)
>
> Nebulizers, CPAPs, BiPAPs and APAPs are allowed in carry-on bags but
> must be removed from the carrying case and undergo X-ray screening.
> Facemasks and tubing may remain in the case.
>
> You may provide a clear plastic bag to place the device in for X-ray
> screening. A TSA officer may need to remove the device from the bag to
> test it for traces of explosives.
>
> Liquids associated with nebulizers are exempt from the 3-1-1 liquids
> rule, in reasonable quantities. For more information, see TSA special
> procedures.
>
> Devices containing lithium metal or lithium ion batteries should be
> carried in carry-on baggage.  Most other consumer electronic devices
> containing batteries are allowed in carry-on and checked baggage.)